# Bootstrap 4: is it better to use ".row" or ".col-12" for a new block? why?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am going to show a little example.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <form class="col-12 form-group">
      // some code
    </form>

    <div class="col-12">
      // some text for description
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, theses columns are in the same row, but I can separate them. Like that:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <form class="col-12 form-group">
      // some code
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      // some text for description
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

There will be any differece?

Comment: You can use both as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the first case they belong to the same flex container and in other one no. This make them different. You may see the difference when adding more properties:

A trivial one:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex-column-reverse">

    <form class="col-12 form-group">
      one
    </form>

    <div class="col-12">
      two
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row flex-column-reverse">
    <form class="col-12 form-group">
      one
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="row flex-column-reverse">
    <div class="col-12">
      two
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

You cannot use `flex-column-reverse` in the second case to change the order.